# UIScrollView updating/loading wrongly

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Im making a preview in my `ViewController` that all my Picked images in `imagePicker` will be in my scrollView,
Yes, I was able to make a preview of it in `thumbnail`, But when I'm logging it in my debugger, it seems to be that everytime my `viewDidAppear`, it also **reAdds** the `scrollView`, so the images count is being added again, making it harder to delete in view due to overlaping of the images. What I needed is to just refresh the `scrollview` whenever the view appears and when I'm adding a new image/s.

Here is a sneak preview of those codes I'm having problems for a long time:

```
- (id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if ((self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])) {
        _images =  [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        _thumbs =  [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)addImage:(UIImage *)image {
    [_images addObject:image];
    [_thumbs addObject:[image imageByScalingAndCroppingForSize:CGSizeMake(60, 60)]];
    [self createScrollView];
}        
- (void) createScrollView {

    [scrollView setNeedsDisplay];
    int row = 0;
    int column = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < _thumbs.count; ++i) {

        UIImage *thumb = [_thumbs objectAtIndex:i];
        UIButton * button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(column*60+10, row*60+10, 60, 75);
        [button setImage:thumb forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button addTarget:self 
                   action:@selector(buttonClicked:) 
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        button.tag = i; 

        [scrollView addSubview:button];

        if (column == 4) {
            column = 0;
            row++;
        } else {
            column++;
        }

    }
    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(300, (row+1) * 60 + 10)];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{        
    self.slotBg = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(43, 370, 310, 143)];
    CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradient.frame = self.slotBg.bounds;
    gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor grayColor] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor], nil];
    [self.slotBg.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
    [self.view addSubview:self.slotBg];
    self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f,0.0f,300.0f,130.0f)];
    [slotBg addSubview:self.scrollView];
}


- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{    
    [_thumbs removeAllObjects];
    for(int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) 
    { 
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

        NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Images%d.png", i]]; 
        if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:savedImagePath]){ 
            [self addImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:savedImagePath]]; 
        } 
    }
}
```

Help would be much appreciated.

And would using this be much of help, removing then adding. Or is this a way to just completely remove/delete all those subview completely, then **REadd**?
Thanks for those whose gonna help.

And could this be helpful? Thankyou

```
for(UIView *subview in [scrollView subviews]) {
    if([subview isKindOfClass:[UIView class]]) {
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
    } else {

    }
}
```

DELETE:

```
- (void)deleteItem:(id)sender {
        _clickedButton = (UIButton *)sender;
        UIAlertView *saveMessage = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@""
                                                              message:@"DELETE？"
                                                             delegate:self
                                                    cancelButtonTitle:@"NO"
                                                    otherButtonTitles:@"YES", nil];
}
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
if([title isEqualToString:@"YES"]) {
        NSLog(@"YES was selected.");
            UIButton *button = _clickedButton;
            [button removeFromSuperview];
            [_images objectAtIndex:button.tag];
            [_images removeObjectAtIndex:button.tag];
            [_images removeObject:button];

            NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
            NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
            NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Images%lu.png", button.tag]];
            [fileManager removeItemAtPath: fullPath error:NULL];
            NSLog(@"image removed");
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to remove all objects from array before adding new objects after you refresh,it might work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a working example : [Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/uiscrollview-grid-alignment/)

I wrote out the code, and I have this.  It will align the view to be 5 wide, and however tall it has to be, and the scrollview will change height.

You will need to create a new `NSMutableArray` named `_buttons` that will contain a list of your buttons.

```
- (void)addImage:(UIImage *)imageToAdd {
    [_images addObject:imageToAdd];
    [_thumbs addObject:[imageToAdd imageByScalingAndCroppingForSize:CGSizeMake(60, 60)]];

    int row = floor(([views count] - 1) / 5);
    int column = (([views count] - 1) - (row * 5));

    UIImage *thumb = [_thumbs objectAtIndex:[_thumbs count]-1];
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(column*60+10, row*60+10, 60, 60);
    [button setImage:thumb forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteItem:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    button.tag = [views count] - 1;
    // This is the title of where they were created, so we can see them move.s
    [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d, %d", row, column] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [_buttons addObject:button];
    [scrollView addSubview:button];
        // This will add 10px padding on the bottom as well as the top and left.
    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(300, row*60+20+60)];
}

- (void)deleteItem:(id)sender {
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    [button removeFromSuperview];
    [views removeObjectAtIndex:button.tag];
    [_buttons removeObjectAtIndex:button.tag];

    [self rearrangeButtons:button.tag];
}

- (void)rearrangeButtons:(int)fromTag {
    for (UIButton *button in _buttons) {
        // Shift the tags down one
        if (button.tag > fromTag) {
            button.tag -= 1;
        }
        // Recalculate Position
        int row = floor(button.tag / 5);
        int column = (button.tag - (row * 5));
        // Move
        button.frame = CGRectMake(column*60+10, row*60+10, 60, 60);
        if (button.tag == [_buttons count] - 1) {
            [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(300, row*60+20+60)];
        }
    }
}
```

Note: In the `rearrangeButtons` method, it is possible to animate the changes.

Here is the code to rearrange the files:

```
- (void)rearrangeButtons:(int)fromTag {
    for (UIButton *button in _buttons) {
        // Shift the tags down one
        if (button.tag > fromTag) {
            // Create name string
            NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"images%i.png", button.tag];
            // Load image
            NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
            NSString *documentFile = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
            NSSting *oldFilePath = [documentFile stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName];
            NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:oldFilePath];
            button.tag -= 1;
            // Save the image with the new tag/name
            NSString *newImageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"images%i.png", button.tag];
            NSString *newFilePath = [documentFile stringByAppendingPathComponent:newImageName];
            [data writeToFile:newFilePath atomically:YES];
            // Delete the old one
            NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
            NSError *err = nil;
            if (![fileManager removeItemAtPath:file error:&err]) {
                // Error deleting file
            }
        }
        // Recalculate Position
        int row = floor(button.tag / 5);
        int column = (button.tag - (row * 5));
        // Move
        button.frame = CGRectMake(column*60+10, row*60+10, 60, 60);
        if (button.tag == [_buttons count] - 1) {
            [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(300, row*60+20+60)];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So ill remove the createScrollView part?

Comment: Im having a problem with this part `int row = floor([_thumbs count] / 4);
    int column = ([_thumbs count] - row);` due to the thumbnails not aligning properly.

Comment: and also when I delete it, it removes the view but not in `NSDocumentDirectory`

Comment: I think I found the problem. You want to multiply the row by 4 while calculating the column. I've updated the code.

Comment: You will need to include a method for handling the deletion of an item that removes them all from the view, then adds them using your original loop. The code I've provided is only for adding individual items.  Could you provide a screenshot or a diagram indicating where the views are compared to where they should be? It is easier for me to spot errors if I can get a visual representation of whats going on.

Comment: Ok. This should fix the problems.  It should be 5 images wide, then add to the next line...

Comment: Ok, now it should work. I dug through some old code, and I think this should work.

Comment: I added the delete method, and tested the methods.  The views I used were 60*60.

Comment: Sorry I must have forgotten to change it. It's you _images or _thumbs array. It contains an array of views in my initial test program. I use _buttons in the version I uploaded to google code.

Comment: I'm sorry. I tried github first, but I was told I didn't have the newest version of the server repo, and I was told the server repo was invalid, so I went to google code. Any suggestions? As for your question, I have some code that may help, however I do not have access to my laptop at the moment. I'll be sure to post a snippet once I can get on in a few hours.

Comment: I can delete an item in the NSDocumentDirectory, but it is the way i rename my images when saving is (example: images1.png, images2.png.....) so when I delete an item corresponds to the index the next I delete become different, so is there a way to adjust also in the NSDocumentDirectory. thank you.

Comment: If you delete the image in the `deleteItem` method, you can go in the `rearrangeButtons` method and rename the images as you set the tags of the buttons.

Comment: In the `if (button.tag > fromTag) {
            button.tag -= 1;
        }` section, change the insides to `<load Image using tag>; button.tag -= 1; <save image with new tag>;

Comment: Have post the Code for the deleted

Comment: The only problem I can see is that the other buttons aren't being rearranged.  Exactly what is the problem you are having?

Comment: it crashes when deleting with the tag

Comment: try placing a breakpoint on the `UIButton *button = _clickedButton;` line, then step through one line at a time until it crashes. That will give you a pretty accurate point of failure.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14118/discussion-between-kobe-o4-and-nsarray)

Comment: my only problem is the adjusting part. hope you'd still help. thanks man

Comment: Is the problem in the renaming of the images, or in the moving of the buttons?

Comment: Same, moving and renaming in nsdocu

Comment: Please help with rearranging part

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have much time at the moment since its passed midnight, but I can give you an outline.  In your method to rearrange the buttons, you want to loop through each button after the one that was just deleted, and for each item you: load it's image into an NSData, delete the png, reduce the tag of the button by one, then save the NSData to the new png name. I'll see if I can update my example to include images tomorrow.

Comment: I've uploaded the modifications to the link above.  An image gets copied from the bundle and placed in the documents directory with the name reflecting the tag of the button. When the button is deleted, so is the image, and every other images' names get changed to the correct index.

Comment: I've uploaded to github. https://github.com/DavidSkrundz/uiscrollview-grid-alignment

Comment: Hi, Im running a little problem on this. was able to delete but the rearrange button isnt being called. here take a look at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12188281/deleting-in-nsdocumentdirectory-and-uiscrollview