# Deleting in NSDocumentDirectory and UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

Having a problem with my code, was able to have a preview with thumbnail with images in a `UIScrollView`. My images is from `NSDocumentDirectory`. I can delete from it though but I can delete from it (in terms of `VIEW` & in `NSDocumentDirectory`) PROPERLY when I start from the right to left position.

**PROBLEM:**
Now, I can delete anyway, But I have some several problems.

- **First**, though I can delete, the view is not arranging, my `rearrangeItems:` method is not being called also.
- **Second**,Then at first load I can delete anyway I like, but like what I said `rearrangeItems:` method is not being called, so their names
  arent `renamed`.
- **Third**, is at first load, I can delete in anyway, but when I exit the app, I can delete but my images in the `NSDocu` is not deleting.

Hope anyone could help me with this. Below is the preview of my code.

```
- (void)addImage:(UIImage *)imageToAdd {
    [_images addObject:imageToAdd];
    [_thumbs addObject:[imageToAdd imageByScalingAndCroppingForSize:CGSizeMake(60, 60)]];

    int row = floor(([_thumbs count] - 1) / 5);
    int column = (([_thumbs count] - 1) - (row * 5));

    UIImage *thumb = [_thumbs objectAtIndex:[_thumbs count]-1];
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(column*60+10, row*60+10, 60, 60);
    [button setImage:thumb forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteItem:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    button.tag = [_images count] - 1;
    // This is the title of where they were created, so we can see them move.s
    [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d, %d", row, column] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [_buttons addObject:button];
    [scrollView addSubview:button];
    // This will add 10px padding on the bottom as well as the top and left.
    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(300, row*60+20+60)];
}

    - (void) deleteItem:(id)sender {
        _clickedButton = (UIButton *)sender;
        UIAlertView *saveMessage = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@""
                                                                  message:@"DELETE？"
                                                                 delegate:self
                                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"NO"
                                                        otherButtonTitles:@"YES", nil];
        [saveMessage show];  

    }



    - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
    {
        NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
    if([title isEqualToString:@"YES"]) {
            NSLog(@"YES was selected.");
        UIButton *button = _clickedButton;
        [button removeFromSuperview];

        [_buttons removeObjectAtIndex:button.tag];

        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"oneSlotImages%lu.png", button.tag]];           
        [fileManager removeItemAtPath: fullPath error:NULL];

        [self rearrangeItems:button.tag];

        }
    }


    - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
    {
        [_thumbs removeAllObjects];

            for(int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) 
            { 
                NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
                NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

                NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Images%d.png", i]]; 
                NSLog(@"savedImagePath=%@",savedImagePath);
                if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:savedImagePath]){ 
                    [self addImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:savedImagePath]]; 
                    //NSLog(@"file exists");
                } 
            } 
            NSLog(@"Count : %d", [_images count]);
    }
```

---

**UPDATED: new rearrange method**

```
- (void)rearrangeItems:(int)startIndex {

    for (UIButton *button in _buttons) {
        // Shift the tags down one
        if (button.tag > startIndex) {
             NSLog(@"called here");
            // Version 2 ****************************
            NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
            NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
            NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"oneSlotImages%lu.png", button.tag]];
            NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fullPath];
            [fileManager removeItemAtPath: fullPath error:NULL];
            // **************************************

            button.tag -= 1;

            // Version 2 ****************************
            fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"oneSlotImages%lu.png", button.tag]];
            [imageData writeToFile:fullPath atomically:YES];
            // **************************************

            // Recalculate Position
            int row = floor(button.tag / 5);
            int column = (button.tag - (row * 5));
            // Move
            button.frame = CGRectMake(column*61+8, row*61+8, 60, 60);
            if (button.tag == [_buttons count] - 1) {
                [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(300, row*61+16+60)];
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a stack trace of your crash?

Comment: what do you mean by stack of crash? how to find it?

Comment: Did your app crash in the debugger? Then you should be able to see a trace of where the crash occurred from within Xcode, or by typing 'bt' on the debugger console.

Comment: I apparently tried to help you earlier but it sounds like you have a totally different problem now. When you say that your "`rearrange`" method isn't getting called, do you really mean `rearrangeItems:`?

Comment: yes. that method is what i meant.

Comment: So it looks like the only place you try to call it is from the alert view delegate method. What's happening with that when you debug it?

Comment: its okay, but the rearrange method is called, but doesnt rearrange my buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You show "rearrangeButtons" but never use it - I assume the code above is out of date. In any case you have some small issues here:

```
[_images objectAtIndex:button.tag];
[_images removeObjectAtIndex:button.tag];
[_images removeObject:button];
```

The first and last statements make no sense, what you should be using is:

```
[_images removeObjectAtIndex:button.tag];
[self rearrangeButtons:button.tag];
```

To just add a sanity check to the app, try adding this code to the end of rearrangeButtons:

```
int idx = 0;
for (UIButton *button in _buttons) {
  NSLog(@"Going to query button at index %d", idx);
  NSLog(@"Button at index %d is of type %@", idx, NSStringFromClass([button class]);
  // if the button is not a UIView subclass, it won't have tag. If its a dealloced 
  // object then it probably will crash when you ask it its class...
  if(button.tag != idx) NSLog(@"INDEX PROBLEM AT BUTTON ARRAY INDEC %d", idx);
  ++idx;
}
```

EDIT: code edited in loop to print out the object class

EDIT2: So I took your code and put it into a new project, [ButtonManager](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/60414145/ButtonManager.zip). Essentially its OK but you have a few problems. First, you index the file names even if no file exists, so the indexes could get out of sync. Second, you use %lu format for a button.tag, but that is an integer so you should be using "%d". Lastly, you delete buttons from the array but not the images or the thumbnails.

If you download that project, you will see warnings in all the places you need to change to get to work properly. I am not sure why the button indexes got corrupted - maybe other code. In any case there is a data consistency test added to the code - sprinkle calls to that around in your code - if its ever fails then you know your problem is between the last good test and the latest failing one.

The project kicks off a "deleteItem:" message when it starts, and just keeps deleting items in the middle of the array as long as you tap YES.

Comment: its having a crash in with the log, UIImageTag

Comment: Use updated code. Either you have some non UIView object in your array, or the object was released somehow.

Comment: Boss, hope you could help me out in what I am trying to achieve above, is for example I have my images index like this 0 1 2 3 4, when I delete for example 2 its index should be 0 1 2 3, but in my code its like this 0 1 3 4, so when I delete again, it crashes. What I really wanted to achieve is or my idea is to re-write the images in my NSDocument again. thank you

Comment: how are you doing it, when i delete, my aint adjusting.

Comment: Did you download my project? Did you fix all the code that I tagged with "#warning"? You have many errors and I pointed them all out to you. I also told you to put that consistency check all over your code, to help you find WHERE your problem is.

Comment: Do you understand the code I gave you at all? You don't have a single place where the consistency test passed. The return value is TRUE or FALSE, and its NEVER true. You have to fix every occurrance where it fails if you want your code to work.

Comment: Did you read taht consistency test I gave you? It only has a few things it tests. If you cannot understand that I fear you will never get your code working.

Comment: can i ask something, for what is this called for `_buttons = [NSMutableArray new];`
? why is is it initialize with `new` to recreate the array everytime?

Answer (score 2):

Replace your functions with these

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
    if([title isEqualToString:@"YES"]) {
        NSLog(@"YES was selected.");
        UIButton *button = _clickedButton;
        [self rearrangeItems:button.tag];

    }
}


- (void)rearrangeItems:(int)startIndex {

       for (UIButton *button in _buttons) {
       // Shift the tags down one
        if (button.tag > startIndex) {
         NSLog(@"called here");
        [button removeFromSuperview];//remove the button from the scrollview
        [_buttons removeObjectAtIndex:button.tag];//remove the button object from _buttons array

        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"oneSlotImages%lu.png", button.tag]];
        NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fullPath];
        [fileManager removeItemAtPath: fullPath error:NULL];

        button.tag -= 1;

        fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"oneSlotImages%lu.png", button.tag]];
        [imageData writeToFile:fullPath atomically:YES];

        // Recalculate Position
        int row = floor(button.tag / 5);
        int column = (button.tag - (row * 5));
        // Move
        button.frame = CGRectMake(column*61+8, row*61+8, 60, 60);
        if (button.tag == [_buttons count] - 1) {
            [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(300, row*61+16+60)];
        }
        [scrollView setNeedsDisplay];
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.